# Not able to enable the Billing for the new app-id

Tags: google-app-engine

I am trying to enable billing for another app-id.  It is not happening.
I get a confirmation email from GoogleCheckout.  But then the quotas are not enabled.  After, 30 mins, it is still in 'Free' Billing status.

After sometime, I got the reply from GoogleCheckout

Google Services has cancelled your order.  You have not been charged.
Reason: Other (describe below)
Comments from Google Services: "This inactive subscription has been canceled"

What is "This inactive subscription has been canceled" ??

-Aswath